# How to draw multiple bitmaps on canvas with delay in between

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap, delay

I want to show multiple bitmaps on canvas with a slight delay, like fade in animation effect. I have tried postInvalidateDelay() function but not getting any delay.

[here is the code of problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l9JYW.png)

Comment: please share your code

Comment: i m also facing same problem . but couldn't find any solution .